# Insert Update Duplicate Value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
alter procedure spGroupInsert
    (@Group varchar(5))
as
   if not exists (select * from tbGroup where Group = @Group)
   begin
       insert into tbGroup(Group)
       values(@Group)
   end
   else
   begin
       waitfor delay '00:00:01'
   end
```

The stored procedure is designed to prevent duplicates on `tbGroup`. Next, I need to have an `UPDATE` stored procedure:

```
alter procedure spGroupUpdate
    (@GroupID int, @Group varchar(5))
as
begin
    update tbGroup 
    set Group = @Group 
    where GroupID = @GroupID
end
```

The table should be:

```
GroupID     Group
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D
ff.
```

`GroupID` is identity. For Insert SP, I am really sure there won't be a problem.

But, if I execute the Update stored procedure, then I change the `Group`. It will be a duplicate. For instance, if I update Group A to B. Then it will make a duplicate of B.

How I can prevent this in T-SQL in my Update stored procedure?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use "MERGE" instead..?

Comment: can you create a unique contraint on the column ?

Comment: @User2012384, I want to put on separate SP. 'cause it will be executed by another system.

Comment: @Squirrel, yes.. But how can I prevent that on t-sql SP..?

Comment: the constraint will ensure there are no duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tbGroup
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Group UNIQUE (Group);
```

this will handle that in the update stored procedure. It will not update when there is an existing row with the same Group

```
alter procedure spGroupUpdate
(@GroupID int, @Group varchar(5))
as
     begin
        update tbGroup 
        set    Group = @Group 
        WHERE  GroupID = @GroupID
        AND    NOT EXISTS
               (
                   SELECT *
                   FROM   tbGroup x
                   WHERE  x.GroupID <> @GroupID
                   AND    x.Group   = @Group
               )
     end
```

Comment: do I need to change the Update SP?

Comment: Well, ideally, you need to change either the procedure or the calling code to handle possible errors when you try to create a duplicate. Otherwise, your end user will likely see a cryptic error message saying that "constraint UC_Group has been violated".

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, That is what I meant. I want to handle those things in SP. So other system only execute the SP. Do you have an idea?

Comment: for a more graceful handling, verify for duplicate Group and return the status to calling procedure

Comment: @Squirrel, usually you shouldn't answer the same question twice. Just edit your first answer and add extra details to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that for `spGroupInsert` you are sure that there won't be a problem. In fact, there is a problem.

This procedure doesn't guarantee that you'll never insert a duplicate. If two sessions are trying to insert the same value at the same time, you can easily get duplicates.

Both sessions can do the check `if not exists` at the same time and both can proceed with `INSERT`.

```
alter procedure spGroupInsert
(@Group varchar(5))
as
     if not exists (select * from tbGroup where Group = @Group)
        begin
           insert into tbGroup(Group)values(@Group)
        end
     else
        begin
           waitfor delay '00:00:01'
        end
```

The only way to guarantee that `Group` values are unique is to create a unique constraint, which is usually implemented as a unique index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Group] ON [dbo].[tbGroup]
(
    [Group] ASC
)
GO
```

With such unique index in place one of the sessions from the example above would fail to `INSERT` the duplicate and the caller of the stored procedure would receive an error message about unique constraint violation. The caller would need to decide what to do about this error, how to handle it.

The check `if not exists` reduces the chances of getting this error, but it can't prevent it completely. So, with the check `if not exists` or without the check `if not exists` the `INSERT` can fail and your code should be able to handle this situation.

It seems that you are happy to suppress/ignore the error. In this case a simple `TRY ... CATCH` can be enough.

```
alter procedure spGroupInsert
    (@Group varchar(5))
as
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY

        if not exists (select * from tbGroup where Group = @Group)
        begin
            insert into tbGroup(Group)values(@Group);
        end

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;
END
```

With this stored procedure (and unique index), if two sessions try to call it with the same `Group` value at the same time, only one will actually insert the value and the second would silently fail and do nothing. The caller would not know about this collision. In your case it may be acceptable.